# ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelpe / org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL

Tags: hibernate, exception, jpa, entity, mssql-jdbc

Below is the :

JPA Query generated at runtime:  `select m1_0.Patient_Id,m1_0.PLN_ID from [DevDatabase.dbo].Users m1_0 where m1_0.Patient_Id=?`

ENTITY class:

```
@Entity 
@Getter 
@Setter 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@ToString 
@Table(name = "Users", schema = "DevDatabase.dbo") 
public class MemberDetailsEntity 
{ 
    @Id 
    @NonNull 
    @Column(name = "Patient_Id") 
    private String PatientId;
    @Column(name = "PLN_ID")
    private String planId;
}
```

After migrating to java 17, I see that the autogenerated query happens to add square brackets to the schema name (DEVDATABASE.DBO) at the beginning and the end, but it should either add like this
[DEVDATABASE].[DBO] or not add them. Because of it, the query fails to execute in mssql ad it throws

ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid object name DevDatabase.dbo.Users
or
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL DevDatabase.dbo.Users

How can this issue be resolved ?

I tried upgrading and downgrading the hibernate version. But nothing helped.
All recommended annotations additions to the entity class is already done yet not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to write:

```java
@Table(name = "Users", catalog = "DevDatabase", schema = "dbo")
```